# user-mode-linux on Xenial

Tags: 16.04, user-mode-linux

Is the package `user-mode-linux` still available on `16.04 Xenial`? I couldn't find it now,

```
$ apt-cache search user-mode-linux
user-mode-linux-doc
```

Comment: I have described a minimal buildroot setup at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73203/how-to-create-rootfs-for-user-mode-linux-on-fedora-18/372207#372207

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the link "Bug Reports" of that package in Wily points to the following bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/user-mode-linux/+bug/1565448

Which says, and I quote:

> The user-mode-linux package is missing in the Xenial branch. The
>   user-mode-linux-doc package is there, but not the user-mode-linux base
>   package.
>
> http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=user-mode-linux&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all